# Python SCP Socket Timeout

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ssh, scp

I am writing some code that will automatically push files to a server based on a timer. To push the files, I am using Python's paramiko and scp libraries. After the files is pushed to the server, it is removed from the client. I am adding some redundancy in case the VPN or connection goes down, so the file will be saved to a new directory and a push to the server will be attempted at a later time when the connection is back up.

I have been testing this by starting the script then terminating the VPN connection on the client to ensure the file is not removed if a successful push is not made to the server. The issue I am running into is the timeout length - it takes Python's scp about 2 minutes to fully timeout if there is no connection to the server when it tries to scp the file. I want scp to try to push the file for about 10 seconds then timeout if there is no connection.

I did some googling and I added the `socket_time=` key to the scp call:

```
self.scp_client.put(self.file, self.path, recursive=True, socket_timeout=10.0)
```

I thought this would wait 10 seconds when trying to push the file, and if unsuccessful would timeout. However, it times out immediately if there is no connection (which is still fine with me - I don't need it to wait too long if there is no connection).

So I have 2 questions:

1. What is the purpose and use of the `socket_timeout=` key in Python's scp put() method? Why is it not doing what I expected it to do?
2. Is there a better way to do what I'm doing? I am happy with my solution but there are much smarter people on here than me so I figured I'd ask if maybe there is an easier/better way to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: The scp library defines a channel, which points to a transport, which points to a basic python socket.  The socket timeout behaviour is explained here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket-timeouts

Comment: Thanks! So why is it taking 2 minutes to timeout when I don't use socket_timeout= in my scp put() call, but times out immediately when I do. What is socket_timeout doing in regards to Python sockets that's changing the behavior?

Comment: Nevermind - just answered my own question when I re-read it. I'm assuming since I set a timeout value, the socket is set to non-blocking mode and fails immediately since there is no connection to the server. Is that correct?